# Reshape Dataframe with Column Information as New Single Column

Tags: pandas, pivot, multiple-columns, reshape

I need to reshape a df and use the "year" information as a new column after reshaping. My data looks like this for df and will potentially contain more year data and players:

```
index      player A 2012    player B 2012     player A 2013    player B 2013
0          15               10                20               35
1          40               25                60               70
```

My final df needs to look like this for dfnew:

```
index      year       player A        player B
0          2012       15              10
0          2013       20              35
1          2012       40              25
1          2013       60              70
```

I"ve tried multiple variations of this code below and don't have a lot of experience in this but I don't know how to account for the changing "year" - i.e., 2012, 2013 and then to make that changing year into a new column.

```
df.pivot(index="index", columns=['player A','player B'])
```

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), 
                     stubnames=['player A','player B'], 
                     i='index',
                     j='Year',
                     sep=' ').reset_index(level=1).sort_index()
print (df)
       Year  player A  player B
index                          
0      2012        15        10
0      2013        20        35
1      2012        40        25
1      2013        60        70
```

Or [`Series.str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) by last space with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit(n=1, expand=True)
df = df.stack().rename_axis((None, 'Year')).reset_index(level=1)
print (df)
   Year  player A  player B
0  2012        15        10
0  2013        20        35
1  2012        40        25
1  2013        60        70
```

Comment: perfect - thank you! i just had to do one more step to sort by "index" then by "Year" to obtain the final ascending grouping.